# run a ruby file by passing another name as console argument ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a file named data.rb but i would like to run it in the console as another name e.g.

filename = data.rb

I can use `ARGV` to get the filename `data.rb` from the arguments but i need to run it as `ruby newfile.rb`

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:ruby]? How to run a program under a different name is a feature of your operating system.

Comment: I want to run it specifically with from the terminal using the Ruby executable

Comment: Ruby cannot do magic. The name you use to invoke the program is processed by the operating system. Ruby isn't running at that point, because you are trying to run Ruby in the first place! Therefore, by simple logic, Ruby cannot possibly have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood what you are trying to achieve fully.

Would symbolic links (Alias in Windows) help?

```
# on most linux shells
ln -s data.rb newfile
ruby newfile
```

I am sure you can find out online how to do the same on your OS, including Windows.

Otherwise, [loading](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-load) it might be another option.